# Play framework leaking jar files causing "Too many open files" error

Tags: java, spring, performance, playframework

I am using play framework 2.3.8 with spring, which crashed my production server last week with the error "Too many open files". When I did lsof on the server, each of the jar file from the lib folder was opened more than 250 times and causing this issue. What could be the possible reason?

Further more, I am using log4j for logging which is configured in application-logger.xml file. In my lsof result, log file also opened more than 250 times and never closed.

Comment: I have the same issue with play framework v2.6.13. I'm unable to run integration tests from the SBT console. From the heap dump, I see the following:
play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket - has a count of over 18.5k objects.